# How to remove unnecessary content from a function output

Tags: r, shiny

The long story short, I try to do a shiny app which does the following:
If my time series are stationary then try fourier
else try wavelets

But there is the following problem:
I use `ur.df` from `urca` package and whenever I do an Augmented Dickey Fuller
the result is like the following

```
###############################################################
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
############################################################### 

The value of the test statistic is: -0.9401 2.5819 3.3893
```

How can I isolate the test statistic `-0.9401`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please make a reproducible example that calls `ur.df` with some sample data. That will make it much easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the example from `?ur.df`

```
 data(Raotbl3)
 attach(Raotbl3)
 lc.df <- ur.df(y=lc, lags=3, type='trend')
```

What you are getting looks like the output from printing the returned object:

```
> lc.df

############################################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
############################################################### 

The value of the test statistic is: -2.2389 3.7382 2.5972
```

The code for printing these objects gets the test statistic from the `@teststat` slot:

```
> lc.df@teststat
               tau3     phi2     phi3
statistic -2.238865 3.738151 2.597211
```

This is clearly documented in the class documentation for `ur.df` class objects:

```
 > class?ur.df
```

shows:

```
 ‘teststat’: Object of class ‘"matrix"’: Value of the test
      statistic.
```

So to get the first element of the first row of the test statistic:

```
> lc.df@teststat[1,1]
[1] -2.238865
```

Comment: sorry, same answer, same time

Answer (score 2):

The `ur.df` function returns an S4 class object (`ur.df`), the data is stored in slots (to see these use `slotNames`).

One of them is usefully named:

```
# Using the EuStockmarket data from the datasets package (standard in R)
df <- ur.df(EuStockMarkets[,"FTSE"])

slotNames(df)
# [1] "y"         "model"     "lags"      "cval"      "res"       "teststat"  "testreg"   "test.name"

#To access it use
df@teststat

# This is a primative matrix, so then get the value needed
df@teststat["statistic", "tau1"]
```

Comment: Yes, but you should always make sure slots are documented, otherwise the authors could change things, as they can be considered "internal" or "private" (R's S4 class system has no easy way to enforce private class data).